# openvpn windows routes ip forwarding enabled but not working

Tags: windows, routing, windows-server-2012, openvpn, ip-forwarding

I have setup an openvpn network, I have in my client windows two interfaces, one public with IP 1.2.3.4 and the openvpn interface, with ip 192.168.244.10

I am able to ping from windows to the server's interface IP 2.3.4.5 and wireshark says that the source IP address is correctly 192.168.244.10, the destination 2.3.4.5 and this works. But when I try to ping from the openvpn server to 1.2.3.4 (client public interface), wireshark in the client side says that is receiving the request (source IP 2.3.4.5 and destination 1.2.3.4), but no reply is sent.

So as far as I can understand there is no openvpn problem, openvpn normally is sending the icmp packet from server to the openvpn client IP but windows is not sending back a reply. So, why windows is not forwarding from interface 1.2.3.4 to the windows openvpn client interface 192.168.244.10, in order to send reply back to the openvpn server?? I have already enabled this in the registry, firewall also is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the problem. I am running windows server 2012 and turning on IP forwarding was not enough.. I had to enable LAN routing in "Routing and remote access" in server manager by right - clicking "configure and enable routing and remote access" and following the steps in the wizard..